# 1D -> 2D String array conversion

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion, multidimensional-array

Is it possible make a 2D array, for example 3x4 one, from one-dimensional String array? For example,

```
String[] animals = {"Abyssinian", "Beagle", "Bear", "Cassowary", "Chesapeake Bay Retriever", 
                    "Common Buzzard", "Dunker", "Eskimo Dog", "Ferret", 
                    "Glow Worm", "Jellyfish", "Komodo Dragon"};
```

should be converted to `String[][]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. For example (you'd have to tailor it depending on the exact result you want to achieve)

```
public static String[][] convertTo2D( String[] arr, int x, int y ) {
  //if ( arr.length != x * y ) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  String[][] ret = new String[x][y];
  for( int i_x = 0, i = 0; i_x < x; i_x++ )
    for( int i_y = 0; i_y < y; i_y++, i++ ) {
      //if ( i >= arr.length ) return ret;
      ret[i_x][i_y] = arr[i];
    }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a return statement.

Answer (score -1):

This example show a way to load the matrix from the array it.

```
String[] animals = {"Abyssinian", "Beagle", "Bear", "Cassowary",
    "Chesapeake Bay Retriever", "Common Buzzard", "Dunker", "Eskimo Dog",
    "Ferret", "Glow Worm", "Jellyfish", "Komodo Dragon"};

int matrix[][] = new String[3][4];
int apos = 0;

for (int x=0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<4; y++) {
        matrix[x][y] = animals[apos];
        apos = apos + 1;
    }
}
```

You may also access the animal array as a matrix, say you want animal[i][j] you may use:

```
animal[ i*4 + j ]
```

Comment: how is this different from the general solution I provided an hour earlier? OP explicitly said in answer to `Should it work only for 12 elements and 3x4 result?` - "I'm looking for more universal solution." also, `apos = apos + 1;` makes me wonder about your former coding experience...

Comment: @vaxquis: 1st I haven't seen your solution when I stated to answer and a phone call interrupted me, I've seen no warning about that, I'm sorry for that. for the code experience thing you may engage in a private competition, but for the sake of the argument lets make it in Scala, Haskel *and* Erlang, then you may wonder whatever you like.